# Swift/SwiftUI First update of a @State variable not received correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui, switch-statement, state

I am getting some weird behaviour from a switch statement in my SwiftUI view. In this view, when chosenParamsIndex is first updated to a value other than its initialising value (from a selection made through the Picker), the switch statement doesn't read the updated value. I've confirmed that the variable's value is correctly updated.

If chosenParamsIndex is first updated by choosing a quiz option outside of the picker (options 3-5), clicking that same option any amount of times is not registered by the switch statement, until you click onto a second, different option.

Because of the inconsistent behaviour, I'm not sure what the reasoning is for the issue.

```
struct PracticeView: View {
    @State private var showingQuizView = false
    @State var pickerChoice = 1
    @State var chosenParamsIndex = 1
    //Params: 0 = Practice 10, 1 = Practice 35, 2 = Practice 50, 3 = Mock, 4 = Difficult, 5 = Rapid Fire
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    // First rectangle with practice text
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 200)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "chart.line.uptrend.xyaxis")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Practice")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("A selection of random questions.")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Picker(selection: $pickerChoice, label: Text("")) {
                                Text("10").tag(0)
                                Text("35").tag(1)
                                Text("50").tag(2)
                            }

                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            .onChange(of: pickerChoice) { newValue in
                                chosenParamsIndex = newValue
                                print("new picker value")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                showingQuizView = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    // Second rectangle with timer, text, picker, and button
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Mock Test")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("30 Minutes · 35 Questions")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                chosenParamsIndex = 3
                                showingQuizView = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    

                    
                    // Third rectangle as a blank button
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Difficult Questions")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("Test your knowledge.")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                chosenParamsIndex = 4
                                showingQuizView = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    //Fourth
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "bolt")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Rapid Fire")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("3 Questions · 15 Seconds")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                chosenParamsIndex = 5
                                showingQuizView = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Practice")
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingQuizView) {
            switch chosenParamsIndex {
            case 0:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsRand10, isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
            case 1:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsRand35, isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
            case 2:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsRand50, isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
            case 3:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsRand35, isQuizTimed: true, setTimer: 1800)
            case 4:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsDifficult, isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
            case 5:
                QuizView(isPresented: $showingQuizView, selectedSet: questionsRapidFire, isQuizTimed: true, setTimer: 15)
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `.fullScreenCover(item: $selection)` instead of `.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingQuizView)`,
 that is, have a `@State var selection: Int?` and set it to `chosenParamsIndex`
 as a replacement to `showingQuizView = true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `chosenParamsIndex` getter isn't called anywhere in body it means SwiftUI's dependency tracking doesn't detect it - so it doesn't think recomputing body is required and thus doesn't call body when  `chosenParamsIndex` is set. You can force it like this:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingQuizView) { [chosenParamsIndex] in
```

FYI this Swift syntax is called a capture list.

By the way, your body is too big which will make it hard to track down and fix problems like this. Try breaking it up into small Views that only need the data they use in body.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce your problem and I agree, it is a bit weird. I couldn't get it working using the same state variables that you were using. But I found a solution using a different form of `.fullScreenCover` and an enum for the selection. When a switch statement is involved, using an enum is perhaps a cleaner approach anyway:

```swift
enum QuizChoice: Int, Identifiable {
    case practice10 = 0
    case practice35 = 1
    case practice50 = 2
    case mock = 3
    case difficult = 4
    case rapidFire = 5

    var id: Int {
        rawValue
    }
}

struct QuizView: View {
    @Binding private var isPresented: QuizChoice?
    private let selectedSet: String

    init(
        isPresented: Binding<QuizChoice?>,
        selectedSet: String,
        isQuizTimed: Bool,
        setTimer: Int
    ) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.selectedSet = selectedSet
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(selectedSet)
            Spacer()
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            isPresented = nil
        }
    }
}

struct PracticeView: View {

    @State private var quizChoice: QuizChoice?
    @State var pickerChoice = QuizChoice.practice35

    @ViewBuilder
    private func quizSheet(choice: QuizChoice) -> some View {
        switch choice {
        case .practice10:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsRand10", isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
        case .practice35:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsRand35", isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
        case .practice50:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsRand50", isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
        case .mock:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsRand35", isQuizTimed: true, setTimer: 1800)
        case .difficult:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsDifficult", isQuizTimed: false, setTimer: 0)
        case .rapidFire:
            QuizView(isPresented: $quizChoice, selectedSet: "questionsRapidFire", isQuizTimed: true, setTimer: 15)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    // First rectangle with practice text
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 200)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "chart.line.uptrend.xyaxis")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Practice")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("A selection of random questions.")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Picker(selection: $pickerChoice, label: Text("")) {
                                Text("10").tag(QuizChoice.practice10)
                                Text("35").tag(QuizChoice.practice35)
                                Text("50").tag(QuizChoice.practice50)
                            }

                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            Button(action: { quizChoice = pickerChoice }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }

                    // Second rectangle with timer, text, picker, and button
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Mock Test")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("30 Minutes · 35 Questions")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: { quizChoice = .mock}) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }

                    // Third rectangle as a blank button
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Difficult Questions")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("Test your knowledge.")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: { quizChoice = .difficult }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }

                    //Fourth
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .frame(height: 150)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Image(systemName: "bolt")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                                    Text("Rapid Fire")
                                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                                    Text("3 Questions · 15 Seconds")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Button(action: { quizChoice = .rapidFire }) {
                                Text("Begin")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }

                }
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Practice")
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $quizChoice, content: quizSheet)
    }
}
```